# java awt-evenqueue array index out of bounds exception

Tags: java

I have a table which consists of 3 columns. The third column was a checkbox when finished select the boxes and I retrieve the details of the 2nd columns which is e-mail id and transfer the data to those mail-ids. While fetching the email-id from table if only one checkbox is check there is no problem for sending but for checking multiple boxes it shows "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1".

I gone through many sites for solution but still not found.

```
 String mail_sql="SELECT Email,Password FROM login WHERE Username='" + userName + "'";

                String sql="SELECT Username,Email FROM login WHERE NOT Username='" + userName + "'";
                PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = pst1.executeQuery();
                   while(rs.next()){



                    model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("Username"),rs.getString("Email"),false});


                   }

                   pst1=con.prepareStatement(mail_sql);
                   rs = pst1.executeQuery();
                   while(rs.next()){

                   mailId=rs.getString("Email");
                   password=rs.getString("Password");

                   }
     }
       catch (Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }




        mail.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){




   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  

        int rows = table.getRowCount(),j=0,test=0;           
        boolean[] b = new boolean[rows];   
        String[] s={""};
        try{  
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){

         b[i]=(boolean)table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2);

        }

        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){

        if(b[i]==true){

        s[j]=(String)(table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1));
        s[j]=s[j].trim();
        j++;
        } 
        }}
        catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.print("er");
        }

        /*mail transfer*/
 try{
        String host ="smtp.gmail.com" ;
        String[] to = s;
        int l = j;
        System.out.print(l);
        String from = mailId;
        //System.out.print(userName);
        String pass = password;
        //System.out.print(pass);
        String subject = "Image";
        boolean sessionDebug = false;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

        //java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));


        InternetAddress[] address = new InternetAddress[l];

        for( int i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
            address[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, address[i]);
        }
```

I want to retrieve mail-ids from multiple checkboxes those are checked.

Comment: You have an array index out of bounds error.  Simple means you trying to address a element in array which is beyond the range of the current arrays limits. The stack trace will tell you which line is causing the error and you will need to debug your code to determine why.  Also, you're not using prepared statements properly

Comment: My array has required size. And the stack trace doesn't point out the exact line where the error has occured it points on a closing parenthesis.